# Data management API, APS forge autodesk - translated file, can we store in our servers

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have successfully deployed viewer project where we are able to

1. successfully upload our 3D drawing file
2. it is getting successfully translated to .svf file format
3. it successfully getting loaded and played in the viewer as 3D object

Now our question is, can we have the translated file moved to our servers (cloud) and play the same from that URL instead of from forge servers?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative need to be served from the APS managed buckets.

After translating you can delete the **input** file that Model Derivative used to generate the SVF.

As alternatives, you can take advantage of Disconnected workflows, as described in [this blog](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows).

Also, Viewer supports GLTF in local environment (refer [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/gltf-20-support-forge-viewer)).
GLTF can be obtained from SVF using [Petr's convert utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils). You can also refer to [this repo](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extra-derivatives)